# Remove groups based on multiple conditions

Tags: oracle

I have a table similar to the below. My goal is to remove groups for each date where the status moves to either 'Cancelled' or 'Failed', while retaining groups per day that contain other status changes.

| Group | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-01 08:00:00 |
| A | Cancelled | 2021-01-01 13:00:00 |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-02 08:00:00 |
| A | Failed | 2021-01-02 13:00:00 |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 |
| A | Pending Settlement | 2021-01-03 13:00:00 |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 |
| A | Settled | 2021-01-04 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-01 08:00:00 |
| B | Cancelled | 2021-01-01 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-02 08:00:00 |
| B | Failed | 2021-01-02 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 |
| B | Pending Settlement | 2021-01-03 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 |
| B | Settled | 2021-01-04 13:00:00 |

My first attempt was something like:

```
select GROUP, STATUS, DATE
from TABLE TBL
, (
select GROUP, STATUS, DATE
from TABLE
where STATUS in ('Cancelled','Failed')
) FLAG
where (TBL.GROUP <> FLAG.GROUP and TBL.DATE <> FLAG.DATE)
;
```

My expected output is shown below *EDIT:, however it seems to be taking exceptionally long (>10 mins) even when applying date filters*:

| Group | Status | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 |
| A | Pending Settlement | 2021-01-03 13:00:00 |
| A | Pending | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 |
| A | Settled | 2021-01-04 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 |
| B | Pending Settlement | 2021-01-03 13:00:00 |
| B | Pending | 2021-01-04 08:00:00 |
| B | Settled | 2021-01-04 13:00:00 |

Comment: How would you now the last status of a day? There's no column that defines the order within a day. Or does `"DATE"` have an hour portion?

Comment: Apologies, it does have time data as well. I didn't include because I thought it was more important to focus groups that have a 'Cancelled'/'Failed' status within a particular day.

Comment: OK, so you can use it to sort and use `trunc()` to get the day portion only. But if the last status isn't cancelled or failed, does it matter, if there was a status of cancelled or failed before on that day? If not I think my answer applies.

Comment: Yeah, if there the previous day's status was cancelled/failed and current day wasn't then it won't matter. I'm just looking at removing events where Group A/B had a cancelled/failed status on any particular day.

Comment: Ah, OK. See the edit of my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `last_value()` window function to get the last value within a group and then apply your filter against it.

```
SELECT "GROUP",
       "STATUS",
       "DATE"
       FROM (SELECT "GROUP",
                    "STATUS",
                    "DATE",
                    last_value("STATUS") OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP",
                                                            trunc("DATE")
                                               ORDER BY "DATE" ASC) lv
                    FROM "TABLE") x
       WHERE lv NOT IN ('Cancelled',
                        'Failed');
```

---

Edit:

To filter out days where the status was `'Cancelled'` or `'Failed'` anytime during the day, you can use for example the windowed version of of `count()` with a `CASE` expression that gives a non-`NULL` value when the status is `'Cancelled'` or `'Failed'`, or `NULL` (the default) otherwise.

```
SELECT "GROUP",
       "STATUS",
       "DATE"
       FROM (SELECT "GROUP",
                    "STATUS",
                    "DATE",
                    count(CASE
                            WHEN "STATUS" IN ('Cancelled',
                                              'Failed') THEN
                              0
                          END) OVER (PARTITION BY "GROUP",
                                                  trunc("DATE")) c
                    FROM "TABLE") x
       WHERE c = 0;
```

Comment: The edited version of your code works, thanks so much for the quick responses!